# Overriding Kotlin method with generic parameter in java - method clash

Tags: java, android, kotlin, interop

My team is migrating to Kotlin for our Android app, but we still have lots of legacy java code, this causes weird code issues sometimes. This is one of those strange cases.

I have a Kotlin class, call it MyInterface:

```
interface MyInterface {
    fun onMyObjectList(myObjectList: List<MyObject>)
}
```

I need to implement this interface in an Activity, written in Java:

```
class MyActivity implements MyInterface {
...
}
```

Here's how I implement the overridden method in Java:

```
@Override
public void onMyObjectList(@NotNull List<MyObject> objectList) {

}
```

I do want to get a `List<MyObject>` as a parameter, but the IDE throws an error

> `onMyObjectList(List<MyObject> objectList)` in MyActivity clashes with `onMyObjectList(List<? extends MyObject> objectList)` in MyInterface. Both methods have the same erasure, yet neither overrides the other

I can't use a `List<? extends MyObject>` as a parameter as I'm passing it further on to a method that expects a `List<MyObject>`. How can I configure my Kotlin interface so that it actually uses `List<MyObject>` instead of `List<? extends MyObject>` when overridden in Java?

Comment: I made a casual attempt to reproduce this error message, but can't.  Could you add details of versions of tools/etc. that you're using?

Comment: Android Studio 3.1,Kotlin plugin Version: 1.2.31-release-Studio3.1-1. Android target SDK: 27, compile SDK: 27, build tools version: 27.0.3

Comment: I'm not currently at the computer, but if I recall correctly, Kotlin's `List` is declared `List<out E>`, and seeing how you can't use `? extends MyObject`, couldn't you define the interface using Kotlin's `MutableList` or Java's `List` instead? Or is this not an option? Haven't used Kotlin in over a year, so please forgive any ignorance.

Comment: I agree `MutableList` which I think is invariant?

Comment: @VinceEmigh That does work, although I'm kind of wary of using java collections in Kotlin. MutableList did the trick!

Comment: @MarkKeen You're right, it works perfect with MutableList. Thanks!

Comment: It's because `List<out E>` in Kotlin is immutable by default.

Answer (score 1):

If any of the methods do change the list or reasonably could, using `MutableList` is indeed the correct solution.

But otherwise, if you *are* planning to migrate to Kotlin eventually and can't change the other method to take `List<? extends MyObject>` at this time, I would just prefer to use

```
@Override
public void onMyObjectList(@NotNull List<? extends MyObject> objectList) {

}
```

and cast to `List<MyObject>` before passing to the legacy method. This is 1) a safe cast if you don't mutate the list and 2) a complete non-op at runtime (so it won't affect performance).